# Does QDoc support DITAXML or only HTML?

Tags: qt, qt5, qdoc

Does QDoc actually support DITAXML documentation? I am able to create HTML documentation but using DITAXML causes this error.

```
Unknown output format 'DITAXML'
```

at the following line in .qdocconf file

```
outputformats = DITAXML
```

I see the official documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/21-3-qt-dita-xml-output.html) mentions it is actually supported but I couldn't create the xml documentation. Has any one actually generated XML doc?

Answer (score 1):

While DITAXML is still referenced by the documentation, it was removed from quite some time: http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-June/011311.html